# Does co-op allow continued persistent gameplay?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can two LAN PC's play Diablo 3 together via Co-Op in a persistent, continual game? I know the online allows for match making and mission based gameplay, but is there a way to start a fresh game with someone and play a continuous play through from beginning to end (including typical breaks of shutting down PC, and coming back to it). If you shut the game down, go back online, and both of you log back into your characters will they resume the co-op play where they left off?

I am referring to the PC version only right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how partying works in Diablo 3.  It is always online; without an internet connection, you're not playing at all.  That said, yes, you can keep playing a game with the same person.  Rather than choosing a mission at the beginning of each playthrough, just choose Continue, and it will set you back where you left off.  This isn't true persistence; you'll have lost your Nephalem Valor stacks, the maps will be randomized again, and you'll need to clear your way back to where you logged out, since it'll start you at the nearest checkpoint.

Any game you continue is **not** bound to your party; it will allow you to continue without your previous partner, and there will be no warning about it.  So if you play without them, they'll fall behind rather quickly.